# How can I open modal window if it's a list in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a problem with opening modal window using Selenium. 
On this page `https://buggy-testingcup.pgs-soft.com/task_1` there is a link **Treść zadania**. When I click on this, I can see modal window with Task explanation.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container helpers">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10">
                <span class="open-details">Treść zadania</span> | <span id="main-reset">Resetuj dane</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

As you can see there is class **open-detail** so i tried with `find_elements_by_class_name('open-details')`, also with xpath and text link but all the time I get

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click'` when I'm using with [0]
or

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

Can someone explain me how to open this modal? It's not necessary for my test, but I'm just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_elements_by_class_name('open-details')` will returns as list not the webelement.Chage it to `find_element_by_class_name('open-details')`

I would suggest use css selector.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".open-details").click()
```

---

You induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and click.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".open-details"))).click()
```

You need to import libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```